# How compatible are the Windows 7 drivers with Windows 8?

Tags: drivers, windows-8

How do Windows 7 drivers fare in compatibility with Windows 8?

Comment: I think that even some Windows 2000 drivers will work ;-)

Comment: @kinokijuf - Actually most Windows 2000 drivers will not work because of the changes to driver model.

Comment: @Ramhound I wasn’t thinking of video cards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of Windows 7 are compatible with Windows 8, I mean, on it`s functionalities Windows 7 drivers will work for windows 8, but Windows 8 still requires Windows 8 assigned, tested and aproved drivers.